# XCode iOS simulator - application is pixelated

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm a beginner with XCode and I've encountered an issue. When I build my application, it looks fine in the standard iPhone simulator, but when I change the hardware to a retina device, the UI elements of my application become pixelated. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing that because the retina screen is stretching the image you're supplying across more points on the screen. You can supply hi-res images in your bundle by appending `@2x` to the filename

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html: "If you load an image from a file whose name includes the @2x modifier, the scale is set to 2.0. You can also specify an explicit scale factor when initializing an image from a Core Graphics image. All other images are assumed to have a scale factor of 1.0. "

Comment: I've specified retina app icons and splash screens

Comment: And now you need to extend that treatment to your other image assets

Comment: UIImage will auto select the retina (or non-retina) image as long as you don't specify the extension

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [guide to supporting high-resolution screens](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/SupportingHiResScreensInViews/SupportingHiResScreensInViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH15-SW1).

As @RobotWoods mentioned, all images in your app need to have `@2x` versions.

If you're using OpenGL ES, custom code that creates images, or core animation, you need to make sure your code accounts for the display's scale.

If you're using only standard UIKit elements like UIButton, UILabel, UITableView, etc. then all you need to do is provide the `@2x` images.

If that doesn't help, please post screenshots and relevant code of what looks blurry.